# Prevent ESC key action from multiple running in c#

Tags: c#

I wrote a program in C#. I want to have a yes/no dialog box when a user presses ESC key on keyboard.If a user selects **"YES"** in the yes/no dialog box, program should close the form and if he/she selects **"NO"**, it should do nothing and leave the form untouched.

I wrote the following code:

```
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Escape)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to exit?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                Form newform = new Form1();
                newform.Show();
                this.Close();
            }
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

When I press the ESC key, the program shows me the dialog box. When I choose **"YES"** it works fine and closes my form but when I press **"NO"** button, it shows me the yes/no dialog box one more time.

What should I do to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I use this code snippet in some other forms in this program and it works fine in other forms.I can't understand why it doesnt work in this form

Answer (score 2):

[`ProcessCmdKey` is called during message preprocessing to handle command keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I guess you're looking for the KeyUp event, as now you're processing both down and up.

If the user clicks Yes, the form is closed and the Up message is not handled.

Comment: correct - see WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100 and check msg.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN